# Is mixing slugs with numbers & names in WordPress a bad SEO technique?

Tags: seo, wordpress, url

While trying to get friendly URLs in WordPress, I discovered [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-category-slugs-desperately-needed-will-this-ever-be-fixed) WordPress forums post, which states:

> WordPress has a monumental issue forbidding you to use the same
>   category slug more than once. It disallows you from having a category
>   tree like this:
>
> Cars:
>   - Honda (`mysite.com/cars/honda`)
>   - Toyota (`mysite.com/cars/toyota`)
>
> Trucks:
>   - Honda (`mysite.com/trucks/honda`)
>   - Toyota (`mysite.com/trucks/toyota`)

So the question is, how bad is this from an SEO point-of-view to use something like:

```
mysite.com/cars/1-honda/4-red    
mysite.com/trucks/2-honda/5-red    
mysite.com/motors/3-honda/6-red
```

where 1,2,3,4,5,6 are the category ID's.

Would you recommend using this instead:

```
mysite.com/cars/1-honda/1-red
```

or this:

```
mysite.com/cars/car-honda/color-red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashes are considered separators just like slashes are so this will be fine from an SEO point of view. An alternative would be just to use slashes for consistency in your URLs:

```
mysite.com/cars/1/honda/4/red
mysite.com/trucks/2/honda/5/red
mysite.com/motors/3/honda/6/red
```